# Компиляция при помощи MinGW и совместимость

Tags: mingw

Установил себе 32-битный MinGW и скомпилировал сишный хелловорлд командой mingw32-gcc.exe main.c -c -o main.exe
Получился экзешник размером 1 кб, который не запускается на 64-битной win 7. Ошибка: версия этого файла несовместима с версией системы.

В отдельную папку установил 64-битный MinGW. В нем названия компиляторов начинаются с x86_64-w64, но часть имени mingw32, а не mingw64, как я ожидал. Сишный компилятор генерирует файл такого же размера, который тоже не запускается.

В чем здесь проблема? И почему файл такой маленький по сравнению с программами, которые генерирует любая IDE?

Comment: Масса причин может к такому приводить. Начните с проверки динамическая или статическая линковка у вас...

Comment: Добавил ключ -static, но он оказался лишним. Без ключа -c все стало как надо. Что можно почитать о компиляции из консоли, ключах, оптимизации и уменьшении размера программ?

Comment: Документацию на компилятор можно почитать...